# Locating a marriage record for Jacob Bennett and his wife Zipporah in 18th century Connecticut?

Tags: united-states, 18th-century, marriage-records, connecticut

Jacob Bennett was born in 1735 in Connecticut according to [AGBI](http://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?ti=0&indiv=try&db=agbi&h=713851) and [Barbour Collection](http://sharing.ancestry.com/2037819?h=886368&e=ZHVuY2FuLnNwYXJyZWxsQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==). My father's research showed Jacob married Zipporah but he did not cite his sources nor know Zipporah's maiden name. In searching (google, myheritage.com, geni.com, ancestry.com, NEHGS,...) for more information on Zipporah I discovered other uncited references to Zipporah and some give her maiden name as Smith eg:

> 1. JACOB5 BENNETT (ISSAC4, JOHN3, JOHN2, EDWARD1) was born 06 Oct 1735 in Preston, New London, CT, and died Bef. 1825. He married ZIPPORAH SMITH, daughter of SAMUEL SMITH.

which I found [here](http://familytreemaker.genealogy.com/users/w/a/l/William-Walker-OK/GENE8-0010.html) in Genealogy.com.

Note there is some confusion possible when researching Jacob Bennett as he had a son with the same name and there was another Jacob Bennett born nearby only a few years apart. There is also confusion reseraching Zipporah Smith as there is a Zipporah Smith who married into the descendants of William Brewter so is better documented in Mayflower Society research.

Where and when were Jacob Bennett and Zipporah married? What was her maiden name and what can be discovered about her birth?

Comment: What original sources have you consulted? You've mentioned Barbour -- can you confirm you've searched this for the relevant marriage, and candidates for Zipporah's baptism?

Comment: https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.2.1/SYBM-2W7 and http://boards.ancestry.com/thread.aspx?mv=flat&m=580&p=surnames.bennett complicate things -- she might have been an Ames, or somebody thinks so at least (and her mother's maiden name may have been Smith). Familysearch tree shows them having a child Ames Bennett born 1758 Norwich New London but doesn't name Jacob's wife. Have other researchers conflated two families, and have you eliminated this line of enquiry?

Answer (score 1):

```
Hoyt, David Webster, 1833-1921
Title   The old families of Salisbury and Amesbury, Massachusetts : a reprinting of the author's full set of genealogical journals, 1897-1919
Attribution     David W. Hoyt with a new foreword by Gregory H. Laing
Original publication    Somersworth, NH : New England History Press, 1981.
Publication Date    1981
Physical Description    1097 pages : illustrations ; 23 cm.
```

Records of the 2nd Church in Salisbury list Zipporah,  S in relation to Jacob Bennet on pages 431 and 439. The book is held at New England Historical and Genealogocal Society Library (AmericanAncestors.org)